# Internal Channels in spring cloud stream

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-integration-dsl

I started developing an spring cloud stream project. I'm successfully received message from Kafka through @Streamlistener annotation. Before sending the message to any output channel, I have to convert the payload by calling an externalservice or by DB call. I don't want to call the external service or DB method from the same streamlistener method. My question is , can we create internal channels (like Spring Integration DSL flow) in spring cloud stream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. In Spring Cloud Stream, the channel binding to the binder would **only** be enabled based on what binder you use for the channel binding.